# How do I upgrade automaticly from terraform 0.11 to terraform 0.14?

Tags: terraform, devops, terraform-provider-aws

I found this files on GitHub and want to try it out with Terraform, but when I execute the command `terraform init`  I am getting this as output.

```
Warning: Interpolation-only expressions are deprecated

  on main.tf line 28, in module "sagemaker":
  28:   aws_iam_role = "${module.iam.iam_role_arn}"

    ` Terraform 0.11 and earlier required all non-constant expressions to be
    provided via interpolation syntax, but this pattern is now deprecated. To
    silence this warning, remove the "${ sequence from the start and the }"
    sequence from the end of this expression, leaving just the inner expression.
    
    Template interpolation syntax is still used to construct strings from
    expressions when the template includes multiple interpolation sequences or a
    mixture of literal strings and interpolations. This deprecation applies only
    to templates that consist entirely of a single interpolation sequence. `
```

And I figured it out that there are a lot old version in the yaml code. So is there any way I can upgrade my code automaticly?
I tired this command `terraform 0.12upgrade` it was not working, I tried `terraform 0.14upgrade` didn't work

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Do you get an error? Does it not do what you expect? Could you please edit the question to include the text of any error when you run the command or what happens when you do? Terraform 0.14's `terraform fmt` command will automatically fix that specific warning if that's what you want to do. Or you could manually edit the code yourself if you want to remove the warning.

Comment: It's also worth pointing out that this is 3 major version upgrades in one go. You're almost certainly better to upgrade one major version at a time otherwise you'll need to handle mangling state files as you go as Terraform only expects you to upgrade a single major version at a time.

Comment: TF provides [guidlines](https://www.terraform.io/upgrade-guides/0-12.html) no how to upgrade from each version up. Have you checked them?

Comment: @Marcin yes, I changed everything manually and now it is working, I was thinking of something like a command that will do that for me, the ones I saw in the documentation we giving me an errors as I was following the steps, I couldn't do `terraform init` and then continue with for instance with  `terraform 0.12upgrade`. Thank you 

@ydaetskcoR only the manual way worked, Obviously the command `terraform 0.12upgrade` didn't worked because I am using higher version that 0.12, and there isn't a proper command for this version. Thanks